# CodeIgniter passing data into views

Tags: codeigniter

I need my data to get passed all the way from my controller -> page (view) -> users (view). **How can I pass the data from my controller to the most nested view?**

1. In my controller, I get some data called $users.
2. In my controller, I load a view called "page".
3. In my view called "page", I load views called "users".

Here is an **example** of how I think I can do it. Is this smart or incorrect?

In my controller I can do:

```
$data['users'] = $array_of_user_objects;
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

Then in my page (view) I can do:

```
<div>
  <h1>Im a page!</h1>
  <?php $this->load->view('users', $users); ?>    
</div>
```

Then in my users (view) I can do:

```
<h1>Hi my name is: <?php echo $name; ?></h1>
```

Comment: How are you defining $name? You're passing $users, an array of objects. So surely you're assigning $name from one of those objects... $users[0]->name, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are doing things in controller like

```
$data['users'] = $array_of_user_objects;
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

then in page(view) you can do simply

```
<div>
    <h1>Im a page!</h1>
    <?php echo $users->name ?> //if its an object otherwise $users['name']   
</div>
```

and in your users(view)

```
<h1>Hi my name is: <?php echo $users->name; ?></h1> //if its an object otherwise $users['name']
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Answer (score 0):

in controller

```
$users = $array_of_user_objects;
$data['users'] = $this->load->view('users', $users, true);
$this->load->view('page', $data);
```

in 'page' view

```
<div>
<h1>Im a page!</h1>
  <?=$users ?>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not need use `<?php $this->load->view('users', $users); ?>`

but `<?php $this->load->view('users'); ?>`

and you need a loop in your users view like this

```
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
Hi my name is: <?php echo $user->name; ?>
<?php endforeach;?>
```